# How does devoir work in this context?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

In « [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtNRZCEfMUI&ab_channel=JEAN-LUCM%C3%89LENCHON»](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KtNRZCEfMUI&ab_channel=JEAN-LUCM%C3%89LENCHON%C2%BB) at 12:30 to 12:40 the speaker says «...un modèle économique épuisé qui n'aurait dû plus le chômage, la pauvreté et les inégalités. »

According to DeepL that means "an exhausted economic model that should no longer have unemployment, poverty and inequality" but how does DeepL get *to have* in the translation when the only verb is *devoir*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtitles are incorrect, Benoît Hamon actually said:

> *[...] un modèle économique épuisé qui **ne réduit plus** le chômage, la pauvreté et les inégalités.*